# how to save every listbox item into a xml file

Tags: c#, winforms

i have  listbox that reads a xml file and gives the user the ability to add items from one list box to the other. I want to somehow save all item names into a xml file when a user clicks on a specific button. But instead of printing the name it prints this `"System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection"`

I thought i could do this.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("info.xml");
            XmlNode test = doc.CreateElement("Name");

            test.InnerText = listBox2.Items.ToString();


            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(test);
            doc.Save("info.xml");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the *type* of the object, not the content.

```
listBox2.Items.ToString(); // System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection
```

If you want to save the entire contents of every item in your ListBox, you should iterate through every item using something like:

```
foreach(var item in listBox2.Items)
{
    // Do something with item
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I'd suggest using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to concatenate each item.